# ng2-completer selected event not triggered on mouse click

Tags: angular, ng2-completer

As the question suggests, I have a problem applying the [`selected`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select) event for `ng2-completer`.

It also seems to be an open issue with `ng2-completer` because they haven't released any fix for [this issue on Github](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer/issues/302). However there is no work-around solution yet.

Here's the code that I use.

HTML template:

```html
<ng2-completer 
   [(ngModel)]="searchStr"
   [datasource]="items"
   [minSearchLength]="0"
   [openOnFocus]="true"
   [placeholder]="'Please enter'"
   [textNoResults]="false"
   [maxChars]="6"
   (keyup)="onKeyDown($event)"
   (selected)="onItemSelect($event)"
   (blur)="onTouched()">
</ng2-completer>
```

Component:

```js
onItemSelect(selected: CompleterItem): void {
   console.log('selected item');
   console.log(selected);
}
```

It doesn't print anything when I click or double click on any item. I've tried typing Enter as well but it also doesn't work. Please help to suggest a work around solution for this if you have. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ng2-completer implemented ControlValueAccessor internally, you can use ngModelChange event emitter to get emitted value.

**Try this:**

```
<ng2-completer 
    [(ngModel)]="searchStr"
    [datasource]="items"
    [minSearchLength]="0"
    [openOnFocus]="true"
    [placeholder]="'Please enter'"
    [textNoResults]="false"
    [maxChars]="6"
    (ngModelChange)="onItemSelect($event)" >
</ng2-completer>
```

Comment: One downside is it's not actually on selected. `onItemSelect` is triggered on key stroke, because with every keystroke the `searchStr` will be changed. Now I touch this component again and see that's your solution is not applicable anymore. :(

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Even though Chellappan's answer works, but it will not suitable if you want to pass the selected event into other component. You can see that due to `(ngModelChange)`, `onItemSelect` will be trigger whenever the `searchStr` change, and with `ng2-completer`, you can change the `[(ngModel)]` by hovering on the item from the dropdown list. This is quite annoying because there is no property to turn it off.

The other solution is to override `click` event on each `.completer-row`.

You can have the `html` file looks something like this

```
<div class="applicant-search-field" #autoComplete>
    <ng2-completer 
        ngDefaultControl
        [(ngModel)]="searchValue"
        [datasource]="dataSource"
        [minSearchLength]="minSearchLength"
        [maxChars]="33"
        [placeholder]="placeHolder"
        (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)">
    </ng2-completer>
 </div>
```

and listen to `key event` to override the `click` event listener (because the drop down will be shown only if you're typing something searchable).

```
@ViewChild('autoComplete', { static: false }) child: ElementRef;
onKeyUp(event: any): void {
    this.overrideNg2CompleterOnSelected();

    this.hasValue = this.searchValue.length > 0;
    this.valueBeforeHoverOnItem = this.searchValue;
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        this.autocompleteEventNotifier.emitData(this.searchValue);
    }
}

private overrideNg2CompleterOnSelected(): void {
    // we have to do this manually because (selected) event of ng2-completer is broken.
    const dropDownRows = this.child.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.completer-row') as HTMLElement[];
    if (dropDownRows !== null) {
        for (const row of dropDownRows) {
            row.addEventListener('click', this.onItemSelect.bind(this));
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a workaround, I still don't want to apply this if the dropdown contains a lot of item, we might run into performance issue.