# ng2-completer selected event triggered on mouse click is broken

Tags: angular, ng2-completer

I have the same issue as this [ng2-completer selected event not triggered on mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071145/ng2-completer-selected-event-not-triggered-on-mouse-click) - whereby the selected event is broken but the suggested fix doesn't work because it fires ngModelChange each time you type something in the search box as opposed to only firing on the final selection of the item. Furthermore, when it fires when the item is selected, the event parameter is blank when it should contain the selected item.

Here are my parameters, any ideas on a solution? thanks ...

```
<ng2-completer 
[(ngModel)]="searchStr" 
[datasource]="dataService" 
[minSearchLength]="0" 
[autofocus]="true" 
[clearSelected]="true" 
(selected)="onSelected($event)" 
[selectOnClick]="false" 
[fillHighlighted]="false">
</ng2-completer>
```

Comment: can you provide small example on stackblitz

Comment: any solution you got